# Securing endpoints in Spring Boot by rights/roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

```
@RestController
public class AccountController {

    @PermitAll
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        // ...
    }

    @RolesAllowed("ROLE_ADMIN)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/products")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> products() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How to configure Spring Boot to be able to access "/test" without authentication, but "/products" with authentication and checking rights/roles?

Is it possible without mention paths of @PermitAll(like "/test") in configuration?

Comment: Have you tried to make custom _WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter_?

Comment: Nope. Do you have an example?

Answer (score -1):

**Question** : Spring Boot to be able to access "/test" without authentication, but "/products" with authentication
**Solution** :

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/test").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/products").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
```

**Note** : By default when you add spring security, it ask authentication for all the url and you need to specify the one which you do not need authentication. For Example /login should be permitAll.

[Click here for Source code of security configuration](https://github.com/Roshanmutha/SpringSecurityJDBC/blob/master/src/main/java/com/roshantest/WebSecurityConfig.java)

Refer Sample HttpSecurity sample for more matchers example as below,

[image: Refer]

For more details : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html

Comment: Is it possible without mention paths of @PermitAll(like "/test") in configuration? I don't want to mention "/test" twice, in controller and in configuration.

Comment: if you are configuring HttpSecurity in WebSecurityConfig for paths then you do not need to add anything on controller part.

Comment: Even @RequestMapping? Then how spring will know what method to call?

Comment: Lets say If your method is @RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser", method = RequestMethod.POST) and if you have antMatchers("/saveUser").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated() then spring knows from configuration that it needs authentication and role to be checked. Spring has url and method mapping.On console you can see mapping while server starts. for example Mapped "{[/alerts],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.test.model.Alert com.mynet.AlertController.addalert(com.test.model.Alert)

Comment: Please provide your git code link. I will have look to it.

Comment: So, then I need to specify url twice, in configuration and in controller. But I try to avoid this.

Comment: All other endpoint/ urls will be authenticated leaving one you are mentioning in configuration for not to authenticate or endpoints having restricted role concerns. So all other urls does not need to be configured.

Comment: Please provide your git code link. I will have look to it. You did not get my answers well.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it providing the next configuration class. In this case everything is accessible, if not restricted by the annotations.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

}
```

Check [SecurityConfig class here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861189/what-is-the-best-practice-to-salt-a-password-with-spring-security-in-spring-boot/43875887#43875887) for more configuration options.

Comment: What about authentification, can you please provide an example with authentication and @PermitAll/@RolesAllowed? Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe what exactly do you mean by authentication? With this config you can control access using `@Secured` annotations. For more complete security configuration (with custom UserDetailsServiceImp) please check the link in the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861189/what-is-the-best-practice-to-salt-a-password-with-spring-security-in-spring-boot/43875887#43875887)